# Local Proxy Service Testing

Tags: oracle12c, osb

Is there a way to pass the Request in Local proxy service as how we pass in the SOAP based Proxy Service? If no, then how do we ensure that flow in local proxy service is working fine?

Comment: Why not just have a soap proxy that routes to the local proxy so you can test it?

Comment: yeah, but wont the request format be different for both??

Comment: Not if they are both bound to the same WSDL. 

If that is not good enough, you can use something like Tomecode's configurator to switch the local proxy to http before deploying to a test server, if you prefer.